# Where can I get Portable Internet Explorer 8 with Flash Player support and Chrome Frame?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, portable-applications, google-chrome-frame

I searched everywhere and have not found any site where it says that the Portable IE8 has Flash Player and Chrome Frame support. So, where can I get Portable Internet Explorer 8 with Flash Player support and Chrome Frame? Any idea??

Comment: What is the purpose of it? [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/index.php?PortableSandbox) can be used to install IE, I'm not sure if IE becomes portable after it, but you can give a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it backwards. Get the portable Chrome that already has Flash built in and get the IE Frame.

Comment: Rob:
"You can then carry the USB drive **bold**to another computer where Sandboxie is installed**bold**, and set the container folder on that other computer to drive P. Through the Sandboxie Start menu, you will see the menu shortcuts installed by the game, and when you start it, the game will find its settings as they were recorded in the sandboxed registry.

Note that Sandboxie itself is not portable software, but it facilitates the portability of a large number of applications."

Comment: Sandboxie is not portable itself, so no, it is not an ideal solution.

Peter:

I got portable Chrome with built-in Flash, and I installed Neptune for Webkit browsers :) Thanks a lot for hinting me at the inverse logic!